# Machine Learning & Image Recognition: How to start?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-recognition

I've been a full stack web developer for 15 years now and would like to be involved in machine learning. There is already a specific scenario for this: We have a database with several million products and one product image each. There is also a database with about 5000 terms.

A product image is linked to several terms (usually 3 - 20), whereby the link still has a weighting (1-100%). The terms are always of a visual nature, that is, they describe a visually recognizable feature on the image.

The aim should now be to upload a new image (of course with thematic reference) and to get an answer with possible terms (including probability) based on the already classified images.

Do you have any advice on how best to start here? Is there a framework that comes close to this scenario? Is TensorFlow relevant for this task? What new language should I learn?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You may get better response if you ask this question on `https://datascience.stackexchange.com/`

Comment: Removed unrelated "ml" tag, which does *not* stand for machine learning.

Comment: Image classification is a standard task in machine learning and there are tons of tutorials online. You can e.g. check out the ["official" TensorFlow tutorial on Image Recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/image_recognition) or [this blog post on image classification with Keras](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow can be used, it's pretty "low-level" though. So if you're just starting out you might be better off using Keras with a TensorFlow backend as it's more userfriendly.

Regarding languages you will probably use Python. So if you don't know it already you should get started. In my opinion you can also learn it on-the-fly while practicing as you're already a developer.

As for tutorials you will have to probably pick out the relevant bits of many different tutorials. You could get started with something like this:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. A framework like Keras is what I was looking for!